# Repeat each row N times in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, repeat, transpose

I have a column containing 3 rows and I want to be able to repeat those rows 5 times each.

**Example**

| Name |
| --- |
| Dog |
| Cat |
| Ball |

**Desired Output**

| Output |
| --- |
| Dog |
| Dog |
| Dog |
| Dog |
| Dog |
| Cat |
| Cat |
| Cat |
| Cat |
| Cat |
| Ball |
| Ball |
| Ball |
| Ball |
| Ball |

Here's what I have tried:

```
=TRANSPOSE(split(rept(join(";",A:A)&";",5),";"))
```

**My attempt produces:**

| Output |
| --- |
| Dog |
| Cat |
| Ball |
| Dog |
| Cat |
| Ball |
| Dog |
| Cat |
| Ball |
| Dog |
| Cat |
| Ball |
| Dog |
| Cat |
| Ball |

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT(A1:A3&"♠", 5), ,999^99), "♠"))))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=SORT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(
 REPT(A1:A3&"♠", 5)), ,999^99), "♠"))), 1, 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Did what you posted and it worked. Then, I narrowed it down to just `SORT()` and it still seemed to work great! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @WesFoster note that JOIN is limited to 50000 characters

Answer (score 15):

Without splitting and joining and other string manipulations,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A4),5),A2:A4)))
```

- `A2:A4` The range to repeat
- `5` Number of times to repeat
- `SEQUENCE` to create a 2D array of numbers
- `IF` to transpose a 1D array `A2:A4` to a 2D array of size equal to the `SEQUENCE` array created
- `FLATTEN` the 2D to 1D array.

| A1 | Name |
| --- | --- |
| A2 | Dog |
| A3 | Cat |
| A4 | Ball |

| Output |
| --- |
| Dog |
| Dog |
| Dog |
| Dog |
| Dog |
| Cat |
| Cat |
| Cat |
| Cat |
| Cat |
| Ball |
| Ball |
| Ball |
| Ball |
| Ball |

Comment: This is the best solution. Obviously it has been overlooked by whoever else voted on the rest.

Comment: This simpler solution is easier to explain than other more cryptic solutions

Answer (score 1):

`=transpose(split(join("~",ArrayFormula(rept({Balls}&"~",3))),"~"))`

Where:

- `Range` is the range of text to repeat
- `Reps` is the number of repititions

Note if your text contains a ~ change all instances of `"~"` to another character

Answer (score 1):

here is another trick.

`A1:A3` are dog, cat, ball repeated 4 times in my example.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( FLATTEN(A1:A3 & SPLIT(REPT(" |",4),"|")))
```