# Repeat each row with empty rows n times - google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

I'm trying to repeat each row from the example column n times, very similar to this question ([Repeat each row N times in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55481291/repeat-each-row-n-times-in-google-sheets/55481398#55481398)) however, I am also looking to add n empty rows between each repeating element.

**Example Column:**

| Name |
| --- |
| Dog |
| Cat |
| Ball |
| ------ |

**Desired Output:**

| Output |
| --- |
| Dog |
| Dog |
| Dog |
| Dog |
| Dog |
|  |
|  |
| Cat |
| Cat |
| Cat |
| Cat |
| Cat |
|  |
|  |
| Ball |
| Ball |
| Ball |
| Ball |
| Ball |
| -------- |

As answered in the question linked previously, the rows can be repeated by using:

```
=SORT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(
 REPT(A1:A3&"♠", 5)), ,999^99), "♠"))), 1, 0)
```

5(n) being the amount of times the rows are repeated

I'm able to achieve *'empty'* rows but only at the end of each full iteration using:

```
=TRANSPOSE(split(rept(join(";",A1:A3)&"; ; ; ; ;",3),";"))
```

(Each white space between the semicolon "; ; ; ;" acting as n+1)

| Output |
| --- |
| Dog |
| Cat |
| Ball |
|  |
|  |
|  |
| Dog |
| Cat |
| Ball |
|  |
|  |
|  |
| Dog |
| Cat |
| Ball |
|  |
|  |
|  |
| -------- |

I'm struggling to understand how to merge the two formulas or find a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT(A1:A3&"♠", 5)&REPT(" ♠", 2),,999^99), "♠"))))
```

[image]

Comment: This works.
Thank you @player0 I was hoping you would asnwer this seeing as you solved the previous question also.