# How to repeat row N times and increment date by 1 for each new row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have rows with start and end date. I need to repeat each row N times and increment new date column by one.
N = the number of days between the start date and en date

My table:

| Column A | Start date | End date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10/09/2022 | 12/09/2022 |
| B | 15/09/2022 | 16/09/2022 |
| C | 08/09/2022 | 12/09/2022 |

The result I'd like to generate automatically (new row will often be added):

| Column A | Start date | End date | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10/09/2022 | 12/09/2022 | 10/09/2022 |
| A | 10/09/2022 | 12/09/2022 | 11/09/2022 |
| A | 10/09/2022 | 12/09/2022 | 12/09/2022 |
| B | 15/09/2022 | 16/09/2022 | 15/09/2022 |
| B | 15/09/2022 | 16/09/2022 | 16/09/2022 |
| C | 08/09/2022 | 12/09/2022 | 08/09/2022 |
| C | 08/09/2022 | 12/09/2022 | 09/09/2022 |
| C | 08/09/2022 | 12/09/2022 | 10/09/2022 |
| C | 08/09/2022 | 12/09/2022 | 11/09/2022 |
| C | 08/09/2022 | 12/09/2022 | 12/09/2022 |

I hope my need is clear.

Thanks,

I've tried [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55481291/repeat-each-row-n-times-in-google-sheets), but the solution is for fixed N times while I need N to be dynamic.

> ### UPDATE

I though it'll be easy to reproduce the solution to my exact need, but it's not the case... I've received two great solutions which work with my first example, but not the full need.

Here is an example of the exact need:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8 | Start date | End date | Col11 | Col12 | Col13 | Col14 | Col15 | Col16 | Col17 | Col18 | Col19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | 10/09/2022 | 24/09/2022 | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S |
| T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z | A | 05/10/2022 | 17/11/2022 | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do that using [`REDUCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597?hl=en).

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  {A1:C1,"Date";
   QUERY(
    REDUCE(
      {"","","",""},
       BYROW(
         FILTER(A2:C,A2:A<>"",B2:B<>"",C2:C<>""),
         LAMBDA(row,JOIN("❄️",row))),
       LAMBDA(acc,cur,
         {acc;
         LAMBDA(a,start,end,
           LAMBDA(dif,
             {IF(dif,{a,start,end}),SEQUENCE(MAX(dif),1,start)})
             (SEQUENCE(end-start+1)))
          (INDEX(SPLIT(cur,"❄️"),,1),
           INDEX(SPLIT(cur,"❄️"),,2),
           INDEX(SPLIT(cur,"❄️"),,3))})),
    "OFFSET 1",0)})
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  QUERY(
    {TRIM(QUERY(
            SPLIT(REDUCE(,
                    BYROW(A2:S3,LAMBDA(row,JOIN("❄",row)))&"♥"&J2:J3-I2:I3+1,
                    LAMBDA(
                        acc,cur,
                        {acc;
                         IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(SPLIT(cur,"♥",,),,2)),
                            INDEX(SPLIT(cur,"♥",,),,1))})),"❄",,),
            "OFFSET 1",0)),
    QUERY(
      FLATTEN(MAP(I2:I3,J2:J3,LAMBDA(start,end,SEQUENCE(1,end-start+1,start)))),
      "WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")},
    "SELECT Col"&JOIN(", Col",SEQUENCE(COLUMN(J1)))&
    ", Col"&COLUMNS(A2:S3)+1&
    ", Col"&JOIN(", Col",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A2:S3)-COLUMN(J1),1,COLUMN(J1)+1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ztiaa, it works for my example!
But I'd should have provided the full need instead of a simpler example, because I couldn't manage to adapt your solution to my full need. I've updated my question.

Comment: Thanks again!
*Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 1222. Actual: 1221.*

I've created a document to make things easier https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AiBmfSoJcze8kd1De_tW0TV9C8UxQs5nloYQOsM-QRA/edit#gid=1324050944

Answer (score 0):

try:

`=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"|"&B2:B&"|"&C2:C&"|"&MAP(B2:B,C2:C,LAMBDA(bx,cx,if(bx="",,TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(bx,cx,"d")+1,1,bx,1)))))),"|")),"Select * Where Col4 IS NOT NULL")`

-

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rockinfreakshow, it works for my example!
But I'd should have provided the full need instead of a simpler example, because I couldn't manage to adapt your solution to my full need. I've updated my question.

Comment: Hi.. sorry its a bit unclear from your updated info on what's the input and expected output. it would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic demo data. Cool

Comment: I've created a document where my data is in "Data" sheet. --> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AiBmfSoJcze8kd1De_tW0TV9C8UxQs5nloYQOsM-QRA/edit#gid=1276086066