# Repeat rows in Gsheet according to weeks in a month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have my data looking like this
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LC9I0R8uGVnCZoz1ifKeR-_O1A8RCk76z3KuvB4SVoE/edit?usp=sharing

```
metric             time    Foreast
new studdent    01/31/2023  2000
new studdent    02/28/2023  1000
new studdent    03/31/2023  0
new studdent    04/30/2023  -1000
```

i want to repeat each metric row as many times as many weeks in that month
So the above data would look like this

```
metric             time    week Foreast
new studdent    01/31/2023  1    2000
new studdent    01/31/2023  2    2000
new studdent    01/31/2023  3    2000
new studdent    01/31/2023  4    2000
new studdent    01/31/2023  5    2000
new studdent    02/28/2023  1    1000
new studdent    02/28/2023  2    1000
new studdent    02/28/2023  3    1000
new studdent    02/28/2023  4    1000
........
```

so you see jan has 5 weeks, the row got repeated 5 times and feb has 4 so it got repeated 4 times.
i have asked chatgpt but now help.
used this to get weeks in month but gives 5 for every month

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2), "", IFERROR(IF(MONTH(B2+1)<>MONTH(B2), CEILING(DAY(EOMONTH(B2, 0))/7), CEILING(DAY(EOMONTH(B2, 0)-1)/7)), 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=QUERY(
 {
  ARRAYFORMULA(
   SPLIT(
    FLATTEN(A2:A&"|"&B2:B&"|"&C2:C&"|"&
     MAP(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C,LAMBDA(met,bx,fc,if(bx="",,TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(DATEDIF(eomonth(bx,-1),bx,"d")/7),1,1,1))))))
   ,"|")
   )
  }
,"Select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col3 Where Col4 IS NOT NULL 
label Col1 'Metric', Col2 'Time', Col4 'Week', Col3 'Forecast' format Col2 'mm/dd/yyyy'")
```

---

**LOGIC**

- `ROUNDUP(DATEDIF(eomonth(bx,-1),bx,"d")/7)`: calculates the number of days between the start of the month (`eomonth(bx,-1)`) and the end of the month (`bx`), divided by seven to get the number of weeks, and roundedup to get an integer value
- `SEQUENCE`: returns the number of weeks in the month, where start=1, and end = `roundup(datedif))`
- `TRANSPOSE`: creates the SEQUENCE as additional data columns for each row so that they can be displayed as values on each row
- `SPLIT(FLATTEN))`: note that each value was joined by `&"|"&`; `flatten` returns the values for each row, and `split` breaks the values into Columns
- `ARRAYFORMULA`: enables the formula to return each row in the data range
- `QUERY`: returns the columns in the correct order, formats the date, and labels the headers.

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: sample]

---

Adapted from the answer by @rockinfreakshow in [How to repeat row N times and increment date by 1 for each new row in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74775818/1330560)

---

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your answer, it really helps. I just have one more thing to ask, I want the weeks to increment till 52/53 depending on the year. In current answer, the week gets reset when month changes.

Comment: The weeks **are** reset as the month changes. I understood that this was your goal. So far as incrementing to 52/53, suggest you post this as a new question. And be sure to include an example of the outcome that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @shahidhamdam You will have noticed that using `ROUNDUP(DATEDIF(eomonth(bx,-1),bx,"d")/7)` results in 59 weeks over a 12 month period. May I suggest that, when you post your new question, you also explain _why_ you are counting weeks per month. This may help users when considering an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula,
Make sure to replace the A2:C5 reference with your specific data range. The formula is designed to work with a single data range (r) to perform a series of operations

```
=LAMBDA(r, QUERY(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(REPT(BYROW(r, LAMBDA(j, TEXTJOIN("|",,j)&"|")), BYROW(INDEX(r,,2), LAMBDA(i, CEILING(DAY(i)/7)))), "|"))), 3), "Where Col1 <> ''"))(A2:C5)
```

[image]

#### Explanation:

1. **LAMBDA Function:**

   - `LAMBDA(r, ...)` defines a lambda function that takes one parameter `r`.
2. **QUERY Function:**

   - `QUERY(range, query_string)` is a function that performs a query on a specified range of cells.
   - `QUERY(..., "Where Col1 <> ''")` filters the results to include only rows where the value in the first column (Col1) is not empty.
3. **WRAPROWS Function:**

   - This function is not a standard Google Sheets function. It seems like a custom function or user-defined function. Its purpose is not clear without additional context.
4. **TOCOL Function:**

   - This function is also not a standard Google Sheets function. It appears to be a custom or user-defined function. Its purpose is not clear without additional context.
5. **ArrayFormula Function:**

   - `ArrayFormula(...)` is a function that allows the use of array operations in a single-cell formula.
6. **SPLIT Function:**

   - `SPLIT(text, delimiter)` is a function that splits a text string into an array of substrings based on a specified delimiter.
   - In this case, the delimiter is `|`.
7. **REPT Function:**

   - `REPT(text, number_of_times)` repeats a text string a specified number of times.
   - `REPT(BYROW(r, LAMBDA(j, TEXTJOIN("|",,j)&"|")), BYROW(INDEX(r,,2), LAMBDA(i, CEILING(DAY(i)/7))))` seems to create a repeated pattern based on the second column of the input range `r`. The repetition is determined by the ceiling of the day divided by 7.
8. **BYROW Function:**

   - This function is not a standard Google Sheets function. It seems to be a custom or user-defined function. Its purpose is not clear without additional context.
9. **LAMBDA Function (Inside BYROW):**

   - `LAMBDA(j, TEXTJOIN("|",,j)&"|")` is another lambda function. It takes a parameter `j` and joins the elements of `j` with a `|` delimiter, and appends `|` at the end.
10. **INDEX Function:**

- `INDEX(r,,2)` extracts the second column of the range `r`.

11. **DAY Function:**

- `DAY(date)` returns the day of the month for a given date.

12. **CEILING Function:**

- `CEILING(number)` returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to a given number.
- `CEILING(DAY(i)/7)` seems to round up the day of the month divided by 7.

13. **TEXTJOIN Function (Inside BYROW):**

- `TEXTJOIN("|",,j)` joins the elements of `j` with a `|` delimiter.

Comment: Any “Week” numbers?

Comment: Chat gpt explanation?

Comment: @TheMaster Good call, Code formating and partially rephrased, is there any post about how much assistance is allowed?

Comment: It seems it is not allowed: [This includes ... as well as using an AI generator to "reword" your answers.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) . I'm [not of the same opinion though](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384647/). Regardless, SO meta  consensus prevails on SO.  Also, it is not without reason. For eg, even with your manual oversight, look at what chatgpt wrote for `BYROW`, `TOCOL` and `WRAPROWS` function in your answer, which you copy pasted without  giving it thought on what it wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  LET(data,A2:C,
      CHOOSECOLS(
         REDUCE({"Week",A1:C1},
            SEQUENCE(COUNTA(INDEX(data,,1))),
            LAMBDA(a,i,{a;
              LET(time,INDEX(data,i,2),
                  weeks,SEQUENCE(WEEKNUM(EOMONTH(time,0))-WEEKNUM(EOMONTH(time,-1)+1)+1),
                  {weeks,IF(weeks,INDEX(data,i))})})),
         2,3,1,4)))
```