# Is there a way to merge a variable number of ranges in an array together in Excel/Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two arrays. One contains string values referring to other ranges of the sheet (other pages). The ranges that the strings are referencing have a constant column size (horizontal, 4 in this case) but may differ in row size (vertical). The other array contains a list of names. Both arrays are the same size, with positioning corresponding to each. I want to obtain a longer range from this data, with the names of the second array to the right of each range respectively. Preferably with a single function/cell, spilling over to the space required. I would extremely dislike to have to use google appscript/vba script. Layout of the problem:

MainPage:

| Reference | Name |
| --- | --- |
| FirstPage!A2:D4 | Bob |
| SecondPage!A3:D5 | Adam |

FirstPage:

| row# | Id | Amount | Goods | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 23 | 45 | Celery | 120$ |
| 3 | 12 | 34 | Radish | 100$ |
| 4 | 8 | 32 | friedegg | 50$ |

SecondPage:

| row# | Id | Amount | Goods | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 35 | 23 | Lettuce | 32$ |
| 4 | 10 | 64 | Milk | 87$ |
| 5 | 9 | 95 | cpus | 234$ |

Wanted Output:

| row# | Id | Amount | Goods | Price | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 23 | 45 | Celery | 120$ | Bob |
| 3 | 12 | 34 | Radish | 100$ | Bob |
| 4 | 8 | 32 | friedegg | 50$ | Bob |
| 5 | 35 | 23 | Lettuce | 32$ | Adam |
| 6 | 10 | 64 | Milk | 87$ | Adam |
| 7 | 9 | 95 | cpus | 234$ | Adam |

What I have tried:

```
lambda(id, MAKEARRAY(rows(indirect(index(MainSheet!A2:A999, id))), 5, LAMBDA(row, column, if(column=5, index(MainSheet!B2:B999, id), index(INDIRECT(index(MainSheet!A2:A999, id)), row, column)))))(1)
```

\-> works for individual ranges, but I can´t figure out how to merge them (hence the question title) (just replace the 1 with the id of the reference)

```
VSTACK(makearray(counta(MainSheet!A2:A999), 1, lambda(id, _, MAKEARRAY(rows(indirect(index(MainSheet!A2:A999, id))), 5, LAMBDA(row, column, if(column=5, index(MainSheet!B2:B999, id), index(INDIRECT(index(MainSheet!A2:A999, id)), row, column)))))))
```

\-> "result should be in a single row" error

```
reduce({},makearray(counta(MainSheet!A2:A999), 1, lambda(id, _, MAKEARRAY(rows(indirect(index(MainSheet!A2:A999, id))), 5, LAMBDA(row, column, if(column=5, index(MainSheet!B2:B999, id), index(INDIRECT(index(MainSheet!A2:A999, id)), row, column)))))), LAMBDA(array, array2, array&array2))
```

\-> "Reference error": it seems that `reduce()` doesn't work with arrays as an initial value. (I've also tried forcing it with `arrayformula()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `REDUCE` to iterate `A2:A3` and get the `ref`erences
- `OFFSET` to get the corresponding `name`,
- `INDIRECT` to get the corresponding `range` from the given `ref`erence,
- [`IF/SEQUENCE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70380436) to create duplicate names according to the number of `ROWS` in the `range`
- `STACK` the `range` and `names` `H`orizontally and  finally `V`ertically stack the `c`urrent iterator result with the previous `a`ccumulator.

```js
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  REDUCE(
    SPLIT("Id,Amount,Goods,Price,Name",","),
    A2:A3,
    LAMBDA(a,c,
      LET(
        ref, c,
        name, OFFSET(c,0,1),
        range, INDIRECT(ref),
        names, IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),name),
        VSTACK(a,HSTACK(range,names))
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(MainSheet!A2:A)), 
     LAMBDA(a,i,VSTACK(a,
       LET(x,INDIRECT(INDEX(MainSheet!A2:A,i)), 
           {x,IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),INDEX(MainSheet!B2:B,i))})))))
```